# I am seeing a continuous error while fetching the data to the layout of external library

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I am building a clone android application for tinder. I am currently following the tutorial on youtube where he used cardstackview from github, which even I did and followed each and every step but I am getting render problem. This is my first time asking on stackoverflow, apologies for any wrong way of asking or disclosing.

Here is the code for layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".userinterface.HomeFragment">

    <com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView
        android:contentDescription="card description"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/cardStackView"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:listitem="@layout/item_user_layout" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Error received :

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor4611.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at com.android.layoutlib.common.util.ReflectionUtils.invoke(ReflectionUtils.java:80)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.RecyclerViewUtil.setProperty(RecyclerViewUtil.java:139)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.RecyclerViewUtil.setProperty(RecyclerViewUtil.java:133)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.RecyclerViewUtil.setLayoutManager(RecyclerViewUtil.java:96)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.android.support.RecyclerViewUtil.setAdapter(RecyclerViewUtil.java:69)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.setupViewInContext(BridgeInflater.java:473)
    at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:356)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:72)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1101)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:505)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:365)
    at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:450)
    at com.android.tools.idea.layoutlib.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:122)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderTask.createRenderSession(RenderTask.java:742)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderTask.lambda$inflate$7(RenderTask.java:889)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderExecutor$runAsyncActionWithTimeout$3.run(RenderExecutor.kt:202)
    at com.android.tools.rendering.RenderExecutor$PriorityRunnable.run(RenderExecutor.kt:316)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: CardStackView must be set CardStackLayoutManager.
    at com.yuyakaido.android.cardstackview.CardStackView.setLayoutManager(CardStackView.java:35)
    ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the error log, you probably forgot to setup the layout manager for the CardStackView.

You need to add the following code when your view is initialized

```kotlin
val cardStackView = findViewById<CardStackView>(R.id.cardStackView)
cardStackView.layoutManager = CardStackLayoutManager()
cardStackView.adapter = CardStackAdapter()
```

Comment: findViewById is giving error saying unresolved reference

Comment: In your case your id should be `cardStackView` . I have edited my answer. Try copy-pasting and let me know